# Find the length shortest word in a string in Python

Tags: python

I'm working on an assignment where I have to have someone input a string of words and my program is supposed to then pick out the length of the shortest and longest word in that string. I've successfully had it pick out the length of the longest word:

```
def longWord(string):
    alist = []
    length = 0
    for letter in string:
        if letter != " ":
            length +=1
        else:
            alist.append(length)
            length = 0
        return alist
```

So if the input is "happy day", my print function tells me that the longest word is 5 characters.

However, for the life of me I can't figure out how to write something that will pick out the length of the shortest word in the input string. How would I do this?

Comment: Nah, you did *not* succeed at finding the longest one.

Answer (score 13):

Easiest way to find the *smallest word* is to use `min` function along with the `len` function as `key` :

```
>>> s = 'Happy day'
>>> l = s.split()
>>> min(l, key=len)
=> 'day'
```

Similarly, for finding the *longest word*, use `max` :

```
>>> max(l, key=len)
=> 'Happy'
```

---

Now the easy part, for getting its *length*, enclose the above in `len` function :

```
>>> len(min(l, key=len))
=> 3
```

Comment: Yeah, that of course works. Seems odd, though. I think for getting the length(s), SolarFactories' solution is more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was trying to over-complicate it. This is significantly easier than what I had before.

Comment: @StefanPochmann : yeah. I too felt weird using `len` twice.

Comment: @A.N : Glad to help buddy.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to know the length, and not the actual word, you can use:

```
def length(s):
    l = map(len, s.split())
    return max(l), min(l)
```

Comment: Watch out, this answer assumes Python 2. On Python 3 you need to do `list(map(...))`.

Comment: I am aware but wasn't sure of whether `max` or `min` would evaluate the generator object.

Comment: `max` and `min` each accept generators. The problem is that `max` will exhaust the generator, and then `min` will error out because the generator is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
s = "This is a template sentence"
final_data = sorted(s.split(), key=len)
minimum = final_data[0]
maximum = final_data[-1]
```

Comment: `lambda x:len(x)` is just `len`

Comment: @Blender thank you for pointing that out. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Sorting is more expensive than a linear search using `min`